# com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.ChromiumProcessStartupFailureException: Process exit code: 17

Tags: jxbrowser

When I start up the JxBrowser, I encountered the following stack trace. This is my first time to see this exception. Could you please explain what does Process exit code 17 mean ?

```
com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.ChromiumProcessStartupFailureException: Process exit code: 17
   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.internal.EngineImpl.throwExceptionAndCleanup(EngineImpl.java:371)
   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.internal.EngineImpl.newInstance(EngineImppl.java:371)
   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine.newInstance(Engine.java:96)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 17 means that JxBrowser failed to establish an RPC connection between the client and the native side.

To say more, we'd like to check the full logs. Please, enable full JxBrowser logs as it's described in this article, reproduce the issue and send us the logs: https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/troubleshooting.html#logging

Please feel free to contact us at customer-care@teamdev.com